# OpenXML EmbeddedPackagePart and the cache

Tags: .net, excel, powerpoint, openxml

I have read all about updating charts linked to Excel data in Powerpoint. I have done this successully - updating both the underlying spreadsheet AND the numbering cache.
I assume my current problem is very similar - only I can't find the cache! Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Instead of a Powerpoint chart (which has the Embedded Package part and a number cache), I just have cells copied from the embedded Excel and they are directly embedded into the slide.
I can update the underlying data and, as usual, if I choose to "Edit" my embedded cells, I see my updated data, and when I come back to my Powerpoint doc - all the data is showing correctly. So I guess it's similar problem but where is the cache for me to update??

currently using the PresentationDocument.SlideParts[0].EmbeddedPackageParts[0] for updating the underlying data (not actually using index 0 but that's the gist).

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I hope I did not misunderstood you, nevertheless I presume you have something like the following:

[image: Presentation with embedded Excel]

And what you want is to update that data which is seen when this presentation is opened in MS PowerPoint, is that correct?

Unfortunately the problem is that this is not some cached value (per se), this is actually an image. Try unzipping your PPTX file into a folder and check the "\ppt\media" sub-folder, you should be able to locate an image (probably of EMF format) that is used for representing that embedded content.
In my above sample case, I have "\ppt\media\image1.emf":

[image: Screenshot of EMF image]

So you'll need to update that image representation and unfortunately I do not believe OpenXML SDK will be able to help you with this. You'll have to search for some tool/utility that is able to render or convert an XLSX file into an image.

Comment: ah ok. When I added it to the Powerpoint presentation, I had a number of Paste Options. I chose embed, not picture as I assumed then I could just update the underlying data and it would show.....
That's a super pain then!

Not sure how I unzip the PPTX file? Using the Open XML SDK tool I can see a node called image18.emf which I assume is it - but I can't see what that image is using that particular tool.
Is there a better way of showing those cells where I can just update the data?
Thanks

Comment: First regarding the unzip, note that all Office Open XML formats (which include DOCX, XLSX, PPTX) are essentially ZIP files and you can unzip them with any ZIP tool/program/utility. For example try renaming your presentation file's extension from ".pptx" to ".zip" and then right click it and select "Extract All...". Second regarding the better way, I'm not sure if this is better for your but I would try re-creating a table in a presentation, I believe it's [ShapeTree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.presentation.shapetree(v=office.15).aspx) element in OOXML SDK.

Comment: In other words instead of embedding XLSX file into PPTX you could try reading the XLSX file and creating a table from it in PPTX. This task should be achievable by using just the OOXML SDK. However depending on your exact needs (how accurate mapping do you want to get, e. g. is it just values or should it include exact styling and formatting and etc.) this could turn out to be simple or complex task to code out.

Comment: Actually I was mistaken about ShapeTree, that is just one of the parent elements for a table element, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.table(v=office.15).aspx) is the right element. FYI when working with OOXML SDK I would recommend you to use Open XML SDK Productivity Tool.

Comment: ok thanks. Yes it needs the exact styling and formatting but I guess I can probably just recreate that directly in the slide. I will look into it.
I was using a template give to me by the business and just trying to update the data - but I might have to change the template in this instance
Thanks for your help

Comment: no, just realised I can't do that. There is conditional formatting including icon sets. Grrrrr. This is going to be a pain.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af210908-0c40-426f-9a99-040d61bf41e6/how-to-force-update-of-preview-images-for-embedded-files-in-open-xml?forum=os_binaryfile#answers) post which explains your situation in more details, but I'm afraid it does not provide a solution. The only thing that I can suggest you is to search for a tool or a library that can convert XLSX to image. You could retrieve that embedded XLSX as a stream and provide it to "that" tool, you would then use the output EMF file to replace the existing file in your presentation file.